# Windows DNS keeps re-registering deleted ip addresses

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, internal-dns

I have 2 nameservers running Windows Server 2008.  On these servers we have routeable and private/non-routeable ( 10. _ . _ ._ ) IPs.

The problem is that a query for the nameserver's network name returns non-routeable ips.  These IPs need to be on the computer but **shouldn't be returned** by DNS.  I have selected the option to not automatically register these IPs in DNS.

I have also deleted these non-routeable IPs manually in DNS.

My problem is that everytime I delete these IPs, they are created again in DNS.  I have turned off dynamic updates on the zone on the server side **and** set the interface to not register in DNS on the client site!  But the IPs still show up.

Also, I have tried fixing the nameserver ( NS ) records on the zone to be the 2 IPs we need them to be.  But sure enough, the non-routeable IPs get added as NS records repeatedly after being deleted.

How can I get back crontrol of my DNS?
How can I get Windows to stop dynamically adding IPs I am deleting?

Answer (score 4):

Found the issue.

I forgot to choose the interfaces that DNS listens to on the new server.  By default the DNS server listens to all network interfaces.  Because of this, it seems to register all interfaces that are enabled.

Right-click on the server in the DNS management snap-in, and choose properties.  You can then select the interfaces you would like.

Answer (score 1):

On the Network Connections with the public IPs you'll want to remove the DNS Server's IP addresses completely.  Just leave the DNS Servers blank for that NIC.  Only have DNS Server IPs on the private IP NIC.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It turned out that I hadn't chosen the interfaces I would like DNS to listen on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running active directory? If you do, please check if you have any abandoned computer records.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am running AD, but that turned out not to be the reason for this particular issue.